# Listview and Spinner Holloeverywhere conflict?

Tags: android, android-holo-everywhere

i use Listview and Spinner holoeverywhere in my Activity,

if i set import

```
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
```

i get error

```
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.holoeverywhere.widget.Spinner cannot be cast to android.widget.Spinner
```

and if i'm  set import

```
import org.holoeverywhere.widget.AdapterView;
import org.holoeverywhere.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import org.holoeverywhere.widget.Spinner;
import org.holoeverywhere.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import org.holoeverywhere.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
```

in

```
 listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                        int arg2, long arg3) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                }
            });
```

i'm get error

```
the method setonitemselectedlistener(adapterview.onitemselectedlistener) in the type adapterview <ListAdapter> is not applicable for the arguments
```

how to fix it ?

Comment: Did you try `listview.setOnItemClickListener(new android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() { // etc`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you need use two Classes with the same name. You will need to use something like this:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    // Your code here
  }
});
```